# adding replace to aplication tag in android manifest But still getting Error

Tags: android, android-studio

I just update Android Support Repository And Google Repository And Install SDK Platform API 25 rep 3 (Android 7.1.1).

After Update `tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"` is not recognizing by android studio!

before update everything was OK. Here is application tag in AndroidManifest file

```js
<application
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:name=".AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">
```

And the Error

```js
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@supportsRtl value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:33:9-36
    is also present at [com.synnapps:carouselview:0.0.10] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-35 value=(true).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:32:5-379:19 to override.
```

So what's wrong?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2GW8.png)

Comment: Just to confirm, [are you sure that you modified the right manifest file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/04/08/why-cant-edit-manifest-android-studio.html)?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes , it's the right one , in MyApp/app/src/main path

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CommonsWare for the link which give the idea. Fortunately I backup always and add projects to zip every step is done.

First As CommonsWare link suggest, I create a new project and add carousel library dependency in gradle which supportsRtl should be replaced in manifest by `tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"` and it worked without error.

Than I delete my project in which I got error and replace it with the last backup , change dependencies to 10.0.1 ... targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 25 . Sync and run the app and it's working like before. I don't know what was wrong by the way!

**SO don't forget backup**